# static variables don't work across .so files

Tags: c++, static

```
Class UserClass{
    public:
     int rollNo;
}
```

In my application I need only a single object of **UserClass**. It is a 3rd party non-singleton class which I cannot modify.

```
File-name: userinclude.h
-------------------------
class Base {
public:
    static UserClass* getUserInstance(){
        static UserClass mUser;
        return &mUser;
    }
};
```

1)I have a file **lib.cpp** which uses **userinclude.h**. Inside this file there is a function **print()** which prints the **rollNo**.

eg. ***cout<< Base::getUserInstance()->rollNo;***

**From lib.cpp, lib.so is created.**

2)I have another file **main.cpp** which also uses **userinclude.h**. Inside this there is a function **setUserRollNo(int r)** which sets the **rollNo**.                                                   
eg. ***Base::getUserInstance()->rollNo = 5;***

From **main.cpp** file **lib.so** is **loaded dynamically** using class-loader.
From main.cpp, **main.exe** is created.

**Problem:-**
After running the application, I observed that even if I change the rollNo using setUserRollNo(), the print() always prints 0; After debugging I noticed that getUserInstance() returns different addresses in main.cpp and lib.cpp. Multiple call from same file gives same address but they don’t match between different files. So 2 instances got created.

**I tried to make the mUser as a static member of the class but faced same problem.**

My application is a single process application and so data-segment(where static is stored) should be same for the entire application . Hence the local-static mUser should be created only once and getUserInstance() should return same address always through out the application. But I am surprised seeing this behavior.

**c++ : 14

os : linux**

Please help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: "loaded dynamically" -- this results in violation of the ODR, because `getUserInstance()` is an inline function, and by loading the library manually you're preventing the linker from doing its job and enforcing the ODR. Did you try removing the inline definition, and explicitly defining this class method in one of the translation units (in the library)?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: I guess this should become an answer; the accepted answer. Why should you keep it in a comment?

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I had tried not having inline and write the definition in one of the library, but in that way the other library gives linking error.

Comment: @Sam, So in this case, when we load dll dynamically,  it has a different data-segment which stores the globals and static separately then the actual application ? Is there any other way in this case to have a single instance ?

Comment: Nope. That's the linker's job. And to fix the "other library"'s linking error you must explicitly link that library with the one that contains the static function.

Answer (score 0):

```
static UserClass* getUserInstance(){
    static UserClass mUser;
    return &mUser;
}
```

An inline function declaration in header file, like this, means that this function actually gets compiled into ***every*** C++ source file that includes this header file. Every C++ source that calls `getUserInstance()` will have this function compiled as part of it. That's how inline functions work, by definition.

The "One Definition Rule" in C++ requires that every function, method, or object, actually appears only ***once***. So, how do you reconcile this?

That's the linker's job. The technical details are not important, but the bottom line is that the duplicate copies are removed from the final program when it gets linked.

If the linker produces a shared library instead, one copy of `getUserInstance()` becomes a part of the shared library. Afterwards, if a program gets compiled and includes this header file, ***and then gets linked with this shared library***, the program's copies of `getUserInstance()` will be ***removed*** by the linker when it links with the shared library. The linker sees that this inline function already exists in the shared library, and removes all other copies, in order to comply with the One Definition Rule.

But if your program does ***not*** link with the shared library this does ***not*** happen. The linker has absolutely no other information, whatsoever, that specifies that this inline function is already in another shared library. Subsequently if the program dynamically loads the shared library, instead, a second copy of the inline function exists and this violates the One Definition Rule.

There's nothing can be done, when dynamically loading shared libraries, to remove duplicate inline code. Only the linker does this.

The only thing you can do is to remove the inline definition from the header file, and compile it into the shared library that the header file belongs to.